# Sync Cpanel Database with AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpanel, amazon-rds

I would like to duplicate and sync my 2 GB database from my existing MySQL database hosted on GoDaddy to aws RDS. I have read about various master-slave replication but I havent found any solution yet that includes RDS and Cpanel.

Comment: Replication is indeed the right solution if you want the sync to be ongoing (i.e. you need future updates to also carry over). Otherwise, just use `mysqldump` to generate a `.sql` file, and import it on the RDS as a one-off.

Comment: Yes but the issue is, is it possible with CPANEL ?

Comment: cPanel is just a (not very pleasant) way of managing services like MySQL. Any MySQL approach should be doable in cPanel, with enough work.

Comment: I need a continuous syncing option with Cpanel and RDS. Is it possible ?

Comment: I already answered that.